# How to POST to the external sites form from rails controller with redirecting to this external site at the same time?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I heve mysite.com (rails app) and there is not mine site other.site.com

There is the form on the other.site.com to which I want to put some data. The data is not sensitive (not a login/pass/...) but it is not working via GET.
So I need to gather data in my controller and redirect user to the form at the other.site.com filling this form at the same time.

I do not need to submit this form, I just need to fill it and leave it up to user to submit the form or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `form_tag` helper:

```
<%= form_tag 'url_where_you_want_to_POST' %>
  ... your form controls
<% end %>
```

More information about this helper you can read in the [rails api reference](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-form_tag).

Comment: one thing thoug, if you use `form_tag` you should drop the `url:`, just the link. `url:` is for `form_for` helper.

Answer (score 0):

you can use JSON to send data:

**site 1:**

inside controller

```
def action1
   #say you want send a @data

   respond_to do |format|
   format.json { render :json => @data }
   end
end
```

**site 2:**

now get this data and generate a form

```
def action2
   @data_from_site1 = Net::HTTP.get(URI.parse("http://example.com/action1.json")) #or you can use html format
   @parse_data = JSON.parse @data_from_site1

# now use this @parse_data inside the View of this action
end
```

I hope you are looking for this.

Comment: I have no access to the site 2

Comment: ok. buddy I think it's something like hacking. Could you gimme a real-time example of this kind of implementation?